# Seprate columns into multiple values using one primary column

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

I am building an ETL process which does some calculation and manipulations.
In one of the transformation,
I have a stored procedure which gives output like:

emp_no | pln_id | cipp | shp | bonus|

I have to convert this into

emp_no | pln_id | cipp

emp_no | pln_id | shp

emp_no | pln_id | bonus

and store into a file

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can join columns into an array and than unnest them. Here's a sample:

```
with proc as
(select column1 emp, column2 currency, column3 cip, column4 shp, column5 bonus
from (values ('emp_no', 'pln_id', 'cipp', 'shp', 'bonus')) as foo)
select emp, currency, unnest(array[cip, shp, bonus]) from proc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the output of the stored procedure into a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stored_proc_output
ON COMMIT DROP
AS select * from my_stored_procedure();
```

At that point, just run the three selects from the temporary table and save those into files.